# Javascript Mail Form?

Tags: javascript, html, email, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mail through Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690094/mail-through-javascript)

Hi everybody, I was wondering if its possible to send Mail form contents through email with Javascript? It turns out my server does not allow php, ftp, cgi, rails, and some other crap. If there is a way, please tell me. Cause I really don't know, I'm 16 and new at html code stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690094/mail-through-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747038/sending-mail-from-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2378027/how-can-i-send-a-forms-contents-over-e-mail-with-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bjavascript+%2Bmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't, unless you just want to open the default mail program with some predefined fields such as subject, From, etc.

Like this (but it's really not so great - just get a better web server):

```
<form action="mailto:someone@something.com">

Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" value="" placeholder="Enter a subject">

<br /><br /><input type="submit" value="Open E-mail Window" />

</form>
```

Comment: Interesting approach. If you have no other choice...

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. To send email, you need access to a packet sending system like sendmail, which is not available from typical browser without another computer (see, server) that runs a process to send mail.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot send mail with javascript. However, you can send a request in javascript to an external server that can send the email for you.

Comment: Not without a hack to circumvent XSS protection.

Comment: You are right, this is not a convenient way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot send email itself.  JavaScript runs on the client side, and it would depend on some process on the client system to send the email, which would be a huge security concern if it was allowed.

Your best bet is to find a better host that allows you to write server-side applications.

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal but you could use the [`mailto:`](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/forms.php) form action.